# Why data i get from google analytics API not match with google analytics web interface?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I used Google API to get data from google analytics, but the metrics not the same with the web interface of google analytics.

ie: I get data on 2015-03-01 - It return pageviews 79

But on web interface of google analytics, it is 80.

I had searched on some question the same me, but almost them show the way to solve is Sampling level.

I tried to set other Sampling level

```
 DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = Service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                                                            endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), string.Join(",", metrics));
        if (dimensions != null)
        {
            request.Dimensions = string.Join(",", dimensions);
        }
        request.SamplingLevel = DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest.SamplingLevelEnum.HIGHERPRECISION;
        request.StartIndex = startIndex;
        return request;
```

after that, the result return the same before, it not change.

So, anyone know this issue?

Comment: 1. are you using exactly the same dimensions and metrics on the website as you are in the API?   2. even if you say sampling level high it will still sample data if there is a lot of data.  only a   premium Google analytics account can prevent Sampleing.

Comment: Yes, i using exactly the same dimensions and metrics because this only happens in some days, almost days return exactly values.i don't understand your mean :" there is a lot of data"? you mean is all of data on google analytics interface or what i get ? I only get for test in one day, and total of row return only 30. And my google analytics account is premium

Comment: If you have a premium Google analytics account you should just contact your account manager I am sure they would be happy to help you.   Its kind of what you are paying for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple its sampled data vs. unsampled data which you can read about here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en

For API work i normally use a web query explorer to verify that my API call's are being sent and responses match to verify the data: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: This is exactly what i want to know. It help me know why data from API and interface not match, thank you very much @koconder